# Typescript import Module '"google-one-tap"' has no exported members: 'CredentialResponse', PromptMomentNotification

Tags: angular, typescript, google-one-tap

I'm trying to import google-one-tap. I get import the library it seems, but typescript keeps telling that there is not CredentialResponse, nor PromptMomentNotification. I've added `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]` to tsconfig.

I've also added this to angular.json:

```
"scripts": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js", "node_modules/google-      one-tap/index.js"
```

Below is my login component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HardcodedAuthenticationService } from '../service/hardcoded-authentication.service';
import { CredentialResponse, PromptMomentNotification } from 'google-one-tap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  username = '';
  password = '';
  validLogin = false;
  cred:CredentialResponse = '';
  prompt: PromptMomentNotification = '';
  constructor(private router: Router, private hardcodedAuthenticationService:HardcodedAuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

    handleLogin(){
      if(this.hardcodedAuthenticationService.authenticate(this.username,this.password)){
        this.router.navigate(['welcome', this.username])
        sessionStorage.setItem('authenticatedUser',this.username);
        this.validLogin = true;
      }
     
      
    }
```